# Cómo agregar a un div una imagen seleccionada desde un carrousel con bootstrap 4

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-carousel

Buen día, quiero aprender a hacer un detalle de producto como lo tiene esta página de muestra para mi proyecto en ASP.NET

https://gsore-demo.myshopify.com/products/copy-of-fresh-green-vegetable

En mi caso para poder replicar lo que está en la página de prueba que dejé arriba hice lo siguiente únicamente con Bootstrap 4, explico:

- Cree un elemento div con la clase container.
- Cree un elemento div con la clase row
- Luego dentro de ese row he creado 3 cols, en la primer col está un div que es donde se mostraría la imagen que seleccionen del carousel.
- En el segundo col, es donde iría la descripción y los botones de añadir al carrito y añadir más producto.
- Y por último en el tercer col está el carousel, el cual he modificado para que en una sola row, estén en este caso hasta 6 cols, y espaciados con col-lg-4 para que en cada col se muestren 3 imagenes a la vez.

El goal de esto sería que a partir del carousel de abajo y según cual imagen seleccionen mostrarla en el div que se encuentra arriba y al colocar el cursor del mouse realizar un zoom, para adaptarlo a equipos y móviles, si alguien tiene alguna referencia o algo para poder estudiarlo seria genial.

De antemano agradecido por su tiempo.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="~/Content/images/aceite.jpg" alt="First slide" width="176" height="176">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div>
            Acá iria la descripcion del producto el botón de cantidad y boton de añadir al carrito
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <img class="d-block w-100" src="~/Content/images/aceite.jpg" alt="First slide" width="176" height="176">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <div class="col">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="~/Content/images/cereal2.jpeg" alt="Second slide" width="176" height="176">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <img class="d-block w-100" src="~/Content/images/cereal.jpg" alt="Third slide" width="176" height="176">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <img class="d-block w-100" src="~/Content/images/leche entera foremost 3600 ml.jpg" alt="First slide" width="176" height="176">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <div class="col">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="~/Content/images/Bebés y niños.jpg" alt="Second slide" width="176" height="176">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <img class="d-block w-100" src="~/Content/images/alacena.jpg" alt="Third slide" width="176" height="176">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Qué has logrado hasta el momento? Muestra lo que has escrito para ver lo que falta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con jQuery es fácil si pones una ID a la img que quieres cambiar. Sería algo así:

```
//.imagenesPeque serian las 3 imágenes donde harás click
$('.imagenesPeque').on('click', function{
    //Guardamos el src de la imagen donde clickaste
    var imagenSrc = $(this).attr('src');
    //imagenGrande será la etiqueta img con el ID donde quieras mostrar la imagen, le ponemos el src guardado
    $('#imagenGrande').attr('src', imagenSrc);
});
```

Añádele ese código a las etiquetas en el on load de la página y debería funcionar

Comment: He realizado lo que me has sugerido y hace justamente lo que necesitaba, he colocado la imagen estática que vendría siendo del producto seleccionado, y con tu código he logrado cambiar la imagen de forma dinámica a petición del usuario, te agradezco mucho el tiempo que te has tomado en contestarme y brindarme una solución, haces de este mundo un lugar mejor. ¡Gracias!